Issue with Op-Amp calculations

The resistor's are all 1 ohm except for the one that is 1/3 ohm. Capacitor's are 2F. The Op-Amp is assumed to be ideal in this case. We want to get a function for the angular velocity of U_out/U_in as in the voltage of the output of the Op-Amp divided by the source's output.
I've gone ahead and set up 3 nodes and changed the AC-source to a current source. Here I then calculate using matrices and at the end of the day end up with a function: U_out/U_in = 4/(1-4iw), where w is the angular velocity.
Then after this I should find a point where magnitude of U_out/U_in = 1 and I get an answer of such: f = sqrt(15)/(8pi)
But when I then test these numbers, the voltage of the source doesn't match up with the voltage of the Op-Amp output. Why is this?
EDIT: Here is how I did my calculations:
First turn the voltage source to current source
Then set 3 nodal points and end up with a matrix of such, when
The current source is , where is the input voltage from the source
We want to determine voltage , which is in this case, same as the voltage at nodal point 2.

U_1 = U_3 due to Op-Amp being ideal
then we just add up column 1 and 3:
We can also remove the row representing I_0 after addition due to it canceling out; We end up with such matrix:


Well, I found that the voltage's did not match, thus resulting in the conclusion that the calculations I did were wrong. The voltage of the input did not match the output with the value of frequency that I got when magnitude of 1/(1-4wi) was set equal to one. Where could I be wrong or is this due exactly to the fact that the capacitors are very dispersive?

@ iamlost - golden rule for opamp based amplifiers: All impedances must be much smaller than the opamps input impedance, but - at the same time - much larger than the opamps output impedance. From this, we have a preferred region between some hundreds of ohms up to  ap.p 100kOhm.

I have now edited the post, where I show how I came to my conclusions through calculations. I can't seem to find what I have done wrong here.

@ iamlost - I must admit that it is not clear to me what your problem is. In the diagram, I see a voltage source - and in the text, you are speaking of a current source.
In any case, your calculation is somwhat confusing and  the result is wrong. Please, during calclation, use symbols only (Rx, Cy) and insert numbers into the final expression. More than, that as mentioned already, the valus of the elements are totally unrealistic - such a circuit will never operate in reality.

I converted the voltage source to a current source, and the resistor then moves to parallel. Yes the circuit is unrealistic but this is just a calculation exercise.

Maybe your calculations are fine (I'm not saying they are), but if your build or simulation uses ridiculous component values, you'll get ridiculous, meaningless results, which can't possibly compare with your predictions.

I understand. It's just that I like to check that my calculations do indeed return the values they should. It's frustrating when I can't confirm the calculations through, for example, a simulator.

Well then, I am truly clueless on how to proceed on this problem, because I have no idea what I've done wrong with my calculations. I can't seem to get to the correct answer provided by Maple.

What is J2 in the [3,3] matrix?

J2 is equal to G*U_out. The voltage source is converted to current source to ease calculations with node method. It's the current coming and feeding to the 3rd node

@ iamlost - because you were asking "what is wrong ?": Besides other errors, at least the minus sign in the denominator indicates instability. But the circuit is stable! Stable transfer functions have a pole with a negative real part ("+" in the denominator).

Yes but I'd like to know in which step of my calculations I made the mistake

@ iamlost I am not motivated too much to follow/correct your calculations because it is - for my opinion - confused and much more complicated than necesssary. Again: Why did you turn the voltage source into a current source? Did you think this would make the calculation easier? My simple approach: In two steps, find the voltage Vp at the non-inverting input (two driving voltages, superposition theorem) and then the voltage Vn at the inverting input. Finally, set Vp=Vn and solve for Vout/Vin.

I was taught to use the "node method" with matrices in this exercise, and with every method I've tried from this thread, I get a different answer. I gotta say, I haven't been this lost a while with circuit analysis...

One way to determine this transfer function is to apply the extra-element theorem or EET. In this mode, you first determine the transfer function with one element selected as the extra element removed or replaced by a wire. The final transfer function is the first one, affected by a coefficient to be determined. Here, capacitor \$C_1\$ is the extra element.
The starting point here is the transfer function at dc, when \$s=0\$:

Now, determine the transfer function without the extra element. It is easy here, we have an unloaded low-pass filter followed by a non-inverting op-amp:

Then, reduce the excitation to 0 V (replace \$V_{in}\$ by a wire) and determine the resistance \$R_d\$ "seen" from the extra-element connecting terminals (this element is temporarily disconnected):

Do the same for \$R_n\$ after bringing back the excitation and solving for a null on the output. We have a zero-ohm resistance for \$R_n\$ in this mode.
I have captured all the components values in a Mathcad sheet and compared my transfer function that I had to rearrange in a low-entropy form with a SIMetrix SPICE simulation:

As a final lap, I took your values and simplified the expression before testing it again:

Simulations confirm the analysis and that is good. The EET is part of the fast analytical techniques (FACTs) toolbox and can be generalized to higher-order linear circuits.

Here is what I simulated.
Note that your resistors & capacitors values are a little "not realistic".
Made with Maple.

Here are the "3" responses of your circuit (two calculated and one of the simulation).
Comparison of my answer via Maple is ok with simulation (f < 10 Hz, real opamp).
Made with microcap v12

